# Google Apps Script Error Exception: Questions cannot have duplicate choice values. GSheet > GForms updater

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I'm working on making a Google Sheet update relevant Google Form questions from a list of cells if the header matches a question. The code runs fine, but for some reason, I continue to run into an error when using a certain set of data that is known to not have duplicates, having run it through =Unique() and used the duplicate removal data tool in GSheets. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EoTHkLlqXuZ8wf-L2rEm1PQ6NUFkO_KTMu7BrzvN-30/edit#gid=0) is a link to the GSheet for the source data. The 'Room Number' dataset is the one that is throwing the error when attempting to upload it to the Google Form, [here.](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1r-mcbZCd4EDHRC-8_gpOJZw8Oaj6IzekzNIxSegEwuA/edit) I've removed the imports and changed data for privacy, but the error is still replicated in this data/structure. Thank you for any insight you may have, I'm hoping someone with a bit more experience can steer me in the right direction. I'm a total novice with coding, so any insight on what I did wrong would be great as well.

```
var ssID = "1EoTHkLlqXuZ8wf-L2rEm1PQ6NUFkO_KTMu7BrzvN-30";
var formID = "1r-mcbZCd4EDHRC-8_gpOJZw8Oaj6IzekzNIxSegEwuA";

var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("QTR Inspection Data");
var form = FormApp.openById(formID);


function main(){

  var labels = wsData.getRange(1,1,1,wsData.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  
  labels.forEach(function(label,i){
    //Logger.log(label);
    //Logger.log(i)
    var options = wsData.getRange(2, i + 1,wsData.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().map(function(o){ return o[0] }).filter(function(o){ return o !== ""});
    //Logger.log(options);
    updateRoomNumberUsingTitle(label,options);
  });
  //Logger.log(labels);

}



function updateRoomNumberUsingTitle(title,values) {

  var items = form.getItems();
  var titles = items.map(function(item){
    return item.getTitle();
  });

  var pos = titles.indexOf(title);
  if(pos !== -1){
    var item = items[pos];
    var itemID = item.getId();
    updateRoomNumber(itemID,values);
  }
}

function updateRoomNumber(id,values) {
    var item = form.getItemById(id);
  item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Access denied. I have asked for access.

Comment: Granted! Thanks for taking a look. I updated the permissions so anyone that clicks should be able to see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Room #135 has 2 occurences! You have then to remove one of them.

To prevent further occurence, you can change this

```
updateRoomNumberUsingTitle(label, options.join().split(',').filter(onlyUnique));
```

and add

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver Mike! I have no idea why the duplicate 135 got through both a =unique() and data tool in Google sheets. It actually still won't scrub the extra 135. Your addition works flawlessly to ignore any accidental duplicates. Thank you again for your help and expertise.